# Command not found integrated terminal of Ubuntu

Tags: html5

VS code Version 1.7.2
Commit 7ba55c5860b152d999dda59393ca3ebeb1b5c85f
Date 2016-11-21T22:14:18.217Z
Shell 1.3.8
Renderer 52.0.2743.82
Node 6.5.0

I'm working on Visual Code with WebWorks mobile application, when I try to call the command webworks on the integrated terminal I get Command not found!

It seems for me as the current user lack access to that program because the root can access it?

```
root@abd-SATELLITE-C855-2CE:~# whereis webworks
webworks: /root/BB10 WebWorks SDK 2.2.0.15/webworks.bat /root/BB10 WebWorks SDK 2.2.0.15/webworks
root@abd-SATELLITE-C855-2CE:~#
```

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Open Webworks HTML5 project.
2. Run Webworks gives : 
`abd@abd-SATELLITE-C855-2CE:/root/WebWorks Projects/TimeTacker$ webworks
webworks: command not found`

Comment: Your question is lacking useful content please give more detail

Comment: What is `webworks` supposed to be?

Comment: @muru, webworks is the blackberry HTML5 mobile technology.

Comment: @AbuAbdellah and why would a Blackberry mobile technology be an executable command on Ubuntu?

Comment: @muru, check this for details http://developer.blackberry.com/develop/platform_choice/bb10.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "/root/WebWorks Projects/TimeTacker" isn't in $PATH, so to run webworks out of current directory, you will have to run:

```
./webworks
```

Comment: It doesn't work I got 'abd@abd-SATELLITE-C855-2CE:/root/WebWorks Projects$ ./webworks
bash: ./webworks: No such file or directory'
I think that is related to user permission to run that program

Comment: As @muru writes above, how can we be sure that webworks is an Ubuntu executable ? How did you install it ? Could you please provide the output of 'ls -l' and, if there are a file called webworks, 'file webworks'

Comment: I updated the question with more details.

Comment: According to the output of your whereis, webworks command is in '/root/BB10 WebWorks SDK 2.2.0.15/' .. try to cd to that directory and run ./webworks

Answer (score 0):

After re-installing the webworks on user home directory the problem fixed.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT1yH.png)